# find ip address of all devices on network with particular port number open

Tags: java, windows, networking, ip, port

```
 Socket socket = new Socket();

try {
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -i en0 -a -n");
process.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

while (reader.ready()) {
    String ip = reader.readLine();
    ip = ip.substring(3, ip.indexOf(')'));

    try {
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 1234), 1000);
        System.out.println("Found socket!");
    } catch (ConnectException | SocketTimeoutException ignored) {

    }
}

if (socket == null) {
    System.err.println("Could not find socket.");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i found this code on stackoverflow bt it is for mac and i need to find an alternative for windows O.S .
on windows it gives an exception

Comment: Have you done some research and gotten stuck somewhere? Please share the error message, and what debugging steps you've taken to try to diagnose the problem before asking here.

Comment: i tried bt coudn't figure it out

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
 at javaapplication21.JavaApplication21.main(JavaApplication21.java:66)

Answer (score 1):

Well, to begin with I don't believe there is a **-i** parameter for the ARP ([Address Resolution Protocol](http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/inet-pages/arp.html)) used in Windows. There is a **-n** parameter but it's **-N** whereas the **N** is in uppercase. Obviously the ARP command line is wrong and you should be checking this yourself using the Windows Command Prompt window. You can see all the available parameters for ARP by simply entering **arp** within the Command Prompt window.

To retrieve the ARP Table you just need to supply: "**arp -a**" but you'll receive more than you bargained for and it will be up to you to parse out the required IP address to your connected devices which I would think would be Dynamic IP's. Here is an example of a ARP Table from a Windows 10 box:

```
Interface: 192.168.0.25 --- 0x2
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.69          25-ad-42-bb-bd-65     dynamic
  192.168.0.254         b8-29-34-f9-27-65     dynamic
  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  239.255.255.253       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

As mentioned earlier, I believe what you want are the Dynamic IP Addresses but whatever it is you want it will be up to you to parse out and clean up the data. When you do parse out the desired data it would be a good idea to place it into a **List** Array. Below I provide a small runnable which should work on your Windows computer:

```
package networkdevices;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NetworkDevices {
    private static int port = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getNetworkDevices();
    }

    private static void getNetworkDevices(){
        Socket socket = new Socket();

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a"); 
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String ip = null;
            List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<>(); // List<> Array to hold dynamic IP Addresses
            while ((ip = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                ip = ip.trim();     // Trim the data
                if (!ip.equals("")) { 
                    if (!ip.equals("")) {
                        // Remove all the unwanted spaces between data provided by 
                        // the ARP Table when it is generated.
                        while (ip.contains("  ")) { ip = ip.trim().replace("  ", " "); }
                        // Split each data line into a String Array for processing
                        String[] dataArray = ip.split(" ");
                        // For console output display only...
                        if (dataArray[0].toLowerCase().startsWith("interface:")) {
                            System.out.println("Locating Devices Connected To: " + dataArray[1]);
                        }
                        // If the data line contains the word "dynamic"
                        // then add the IP address on that line to the 
                        // List<> Array...
                        if (dataArray[2].equalsIgnoreCase("dynamic")) {
                            ipList.add(dataArray[0]);
                            // For console output display only...
                            System.out.println("Device Located On IP: " + dataArray[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Close the Reader
            reader.close();

            // try to connect to the device....
            // You'll need to play with this.
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < ipList.size(); i++) {
                    ip = ipList.get(i);
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 1000);
                    if (socket == null) {
                        System.err.println("Could not find socket.");
                    }
                    else { 
                        System.out.println("Found socket for: " + ip); 
                    }
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (ConnectException | SocketTimeoutException ex) {
                System.out.println("\nSOCKET ERROR - " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) { 
            System.out.println("\nPROCESS/READER ERROR - " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is socket timeout exception everytime. it would be great if u could provide with a solution to that

Comment: @Aviral Ahuja, see 2nd answer. I hope this clears some things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

This added answer is towards your second question regarding the Socket Connections. This should have been started as another topic altogether but never the less....

Unfortunately it's not as simple as flopping down a Socket object and expecting it to connect to your found devices. There are several things to consider for each device such as Firewall protection, Anti-Virus protection, Connection requirements of the device itself like the port number, etc., etc. You will also have more success making a connection with a common port like 80 than something obscure like 1234.

In my opinion, your Socket connection should be a little more robust so as to at least receive acknowledgment as to why your connection might fail or be successful. As a matter of fact (IMO), your Socket connections should be done from a different method altogether.

Again I provide you with yet another runnable example but this time I have made a few changes and added a couple more methods. The first change I made was I have renamed the ***getNetworkDevices()*** method to **getNetworkDeviceIPs()** and have it actually return a string List<> Array of the detected device IP's. The second change is that I removed the Socket connection code from the **getNetworkDeviceIPs()** method and placed Socket Connection code into a different method named **connectToDevices()**.

As mentioned earlier, I have added a couple new methods to the new runnable example shown below. The first method is named **getDeviceName()** and this method is passed an IP Address from the List<> Array retrieved from the **getNetworkDeviceIPs()** method. Each IP contained within the elements of the List<> Array is iterated through and checked through this method so as to display the Host Name of that device (along with the IP Address) within the console.

The second new method (as we touched on earlier) is named **connectToDevices()** which is passed the List<> Array retrieved from the **getNetworkDeviceIPs()** method. This method will try to open a socket connection to each Device IP Address contained within the String List<> Array. This method currently returns nothing (it's *void*) but is does display connection results within the Console window as to whether or not it was successful. You can modify this method of course to return the results in whatever you like.

Here is the new example runnable demonstrating all the above mentioned items:

```
package networkdevices;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NetworkDevices {
    public static int port = 80;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Get devices from system ARP Table and
        // place their IP's into a List<> Array...
        List<String> ipList = getNetworkDeviceIPs(port);

        // Iterate trough the List<> Array and display
        // Device names stored within with the getDeviceName()
        // method...
        System.out.println("\nListing Device Names - Please Wait...");
        for (int i = 0; i < ipList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(getDeviceName(ipList.get(i)));
        }

        // Try to connect to each Device that is storred
        // within the List<> Array....
        System.out.println("\nTrying To Connect To Devices...");
        connectToDevices(ipList, port);
    }

    private static List<String> getNetworkDeviceIPs(int portNumber){
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<>(); // List<> Array to hold IP Addresses

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a"); 
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String ip = null;
            while ((ip = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                ip = ip.trim();     // Trim the data
                if (!ip.equals("")) { 
                    if (!ip.equals("")) {
                        // Remove all the unwanted spaces between data provided by 
                        // the ARP Table when it is generated.
                        while (ip.contains("  ")) { ip = ip.trim().replace("  ", " "); }
                        // Split each data line into a String Array for processing
                        String[] dataArray = ip.split(" ");
                        // For console output display only...
                        if (dataArray[0].toLowerCase().startsWith("interface:")) {
                            System.out.println("Locating Devices Connected To: " + dataArray[1]);
                        }
                        // If the data line contains the word "dynamic"
                        // then add the IP address on that line to the 
                        // List<> Array...
                        if (dataArray[2].equalsIgnoreCase("dynamic")) {
                            ipList.add(dataArray[0]);
                            // For console output display only...
                            System.out.println("Device Located On IP: " + dataArray[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Close the Reader
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) { 
            System.out.println("\nPROCESS/READER ERROR - " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        return ipList;
    }

    private static String getDeviceName(String localIP) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(localIP);
            if (address.isReachable(500)) {
                // Device is turned on and can be pinged!;
                result = address.toString();
            }
            else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
                // Device is identified in a DNS lookup!
                result = address.toString();
            }
            else {
                // if you keep getting something like "Unknown Device!/192.168.0.5 then the host
                // address and host name are the same, meaning the host name could not be resolved.
                // This means that either your router just isn't storing the information OR those 
                // devices just choose not to submit their host name to the router, and that is why
                // you will continually get this message. Apparently, there is no way around this 
                // because those device names literally aren't stored anywhere.
                result = "Unknown Device!/" + address.toString().substring(0,address.toString().indexOf("/"));
            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); } 
        catch (IOException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }

        return result;
    }

    private static void connectToDevices(List<String> localIPAddresses, int port) {
        // try to connect to the device(s)....
        // You'll need to play with this.
        for (int i = 0; i < localIPAddresses.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) { System.out.println(""); }
            try {
                System.out.println("Connecting to: " + localIPAddresses.get(i) + " on port: " + 
                                   port + " - Please Wait...");
                Socket thisSystem = new Socket(localIPAddresses.get(i), port);

                System.out.println("Just connected to: " + thisSystem.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                OutputStream outToServer = thisSystem.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

                out.writeUTF("Hello from: " + thisSystem.getLocalSocketAddress());
                InputStream inFromServer = thisSystem.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

                System.out.println("Device says " + in.readUTF());
                thisSystem.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()); }
        }
    }
}
```